# Unable To Strip Tags In Django Template

Tags: python, django

I'm using [Multipleselect](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) module for a multichoice fielld in my app. But I'm having a problem. After implementing the field in my app, and when I tried to render the data saved from database in template, it will output unicode data, instead of it to return normal text data. I've used `striptags`,`removetags` and `safe` to make it display normal text but it's not working.

My models choices is this:

```
THINGS_CHOICES=(
        ('BOY','BOY'),
       ('GOLD','GOLD'),
      ('CAT','CAT'))
```

Models

```
ideal=MultiSelectField(choices=THINGS_CHOICES, null=False, blank=True, help_text='select em')
```

Template[html code]:

```
<div class="vmain">{{ post.ideal|removetags:"[ u ' ' ]"|safe }}</div>
```

It will output this:

```
[u'cat',u'boy',u'gold']
```

**How can I make it display like this in template:?**

```
cat, boy,gold.
```

Comment: What about [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join)? `{{ value|join:", " }}`

Comment: I'm not trying to join, I want to remove tags like [ u''] and make it display cat, boy,gold.

Comment: [u''] is not a tag. It indicates that you have an array

Comment: @akxlr you're right man. It works. Comment below and let me mark the answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as "normal text data", and even if there were, Unicode is absolutely normal. I am also not seeing a view, which is where you would prepare the information to be displayed on the template. What you want is to pass `', '.join([a.lower() for (a, b) in THINGS_CHOICES])` from your view to the template. And fix your indentation!